# How do I get the object created during a constructor?

Tags: javascript

Beginner question here. I am trying to use the class syntax in javascript to make an object. I want to add the object as whole to an arraylist when it is created. I would also like to loop through that array later. My question: how do I add the actual object created in the constructor. Example code:

```
class Example {
constructor(x,y,z) {

  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;


}

}
```

Ideally I want to, when an Example object is created, add it to an array of examples. Can I do this within the constructor function? Also, if I have an array of Examples: what is the correct syntax for for in looping through it.

```
  var examples = []
  for Example in examples
```

Comment: Construct the `Example` and then add it separately.  It would be weird to add it to an array from within the constructor without good reason.  What is your reason behind wanting to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the constructor can simply add the object like this

```
var examples = []

class Example {

  constructor(x,y,z) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    examples.push(this)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just push it into an array:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    Example.instances.push(this);
  }
}

Example.instances = [];
```

And you can iterate that like:

```
for(const instance of Example.instances) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: yes, much better to store the list as a property on the class rather than as a variable in the outer scope (as done in the currently accepted answer).    A `WeakSet` would be even better, though, since the current list would prevent garbage collection.

Comment: @alnitak not really, one can't iterate weaksets.

Comment: Good point, although the point remains that that array of instances _will_ prevent garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

this is a little strange, but you should be able to add this line to the bottom of your constructor:

```
examples.push(this);
```